# Help with constructing a symplectic form on a $2-$dimensional torus

Tags: differential-geometry, symplectic-geometry

Consider the standard two dimensional torus $M=\mathbb{R}^2 / \Gamma$ where 
$$
\Gamma:=\{(n,m)\in \mathbb{R}^2:n,m\in \mathbb{Z}\}.
$$
 I want to

$1)$ construct a symplectic form $\omega$ on $M$, and

$2)$ describe the image of $$C^{\infty}(M) \to Ham(M), \ H \mapsto X_H.$$

My feeling for $1)$ is that it should be along the lines of $$\omega=d\theta\wedge d\varphi$$ where $\theta, \varphi$ are the angle co-ordinates. But I cannot make this precise. Please help with this and $2)$!

Comment: For part 1, the form $dx\wedge dy$ is invariant under the action of $\Gamma$ (acting by translations), so it descends to the quotient. Note that this is a closed nowhere-zero two-form, so it is a symplectic form on the torus.

Comment: Thanks! Any hints for part 2) ?

Comment: How do you want to describe it? The formula is the same in these coordinates as you'd have on $\mathbb{R}^2$, since $\omega = dx \wedge dy$. Then you get, in these coordinates, $X_H = H_y \partial_x - H_x \partial_y$.